# Breeze is excluding entities with foreign key of null when they are expanded

Tags: c#, javascript, entity-framework, angularjs, breeze

I have an entity in my database that has a `null` foreign key.

When I `expand` via JavaScript or `Include` in EF the rows that have that foreign key are lost.

Sql:

```
CREATE TABLE Entity
(
    Id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE EntityType
(
    Id BIGINT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    EntityId BIGINT NULL REFERENCES Entity(Id)
);

INSERT INTO Entity(Id) VALUES (0);
INSERT INTO Entity(Id) VALUES (1);

INSERT INTO EntityType(EntityId) VALUES (0);
INSERT INTO EntityType(EntityId) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO EntityType(EntityId) VALUES (NULL);
```

C#:

```
public class Entity
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

public class EntityType
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long EntityId { get; set; }
    public Entity Entity { get; set; }
}

public class EntityMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Entity>
{
    public EntityMap()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id);
    }
}

public class EntityTypeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<EntityType>
{
    public EntityTypeMap()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        HasRequired(t => t.Entity)
           .WithMany()
           .HasForeignKey(t => t.EntityId);
    }
}

[BreezeController]
public class EntityController : ApiController
{
    private readonly EFContextProvider<EntityContext> _contextProvider =
        new EFContextProvider<EntityContext>();

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Entity> Entities()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Context.Entities;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<EntityType> EntityType()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Context.EntityTypes;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
angular.module('App').factory('EntityTypeService', function(serviceBase) {
    function getAll {
        return serviceBase.manager.executeQuery(
            serviceBase.query.
                from('EntityTypes').
                expand('Entity')
        ).to$q();
    }

    return {
        getAll: getAll
    };
});

angular.module('App').controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, EntityTypeService) {
    EntityTypeService.getAll().then(function(data) {
        $scope.entityTypes = data.results;
    });
});
```

When I examine `$scope.entityTypes` there is only rows with the `EntityId` that is not `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a copy pasting issue with EF.

The mapping should be `HasOptional` instead of `HasRequired`.

```
public class EntityTypeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<EntityType>
{
    public EntityTypeMap()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        HasOptional(t => t.Entity)
           .WithMany()
           .HasForeignKey(t => t.EntityId);
    }
}
```

This will produce all rows of `EntityType`.